# How to call a perl script on the remote node in a preferred format through a php code

Tags: php, perl

I need to call a perl script on a remote node after i do an ssh to that node I am trying to execute the below command

```
$output=exec('$configpath/perl master_program.pl --backupID $id');
```

where I am passing the path and ID values, the perl program needs to be called in that format only, can anyone confirm if this will work? Otherwise, is there any other solution.

I am pasting the full code below:

```
<?php   function create_ssh_connection($ip,$user,$pass,$configpath,$id){
                $connection = FALSE;

            $connection = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);
    if($connection===FALSE){
        #logger('Unable to establish connection with the host: ');
        return FALSE;
    }       
        if(!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass)){
            #logger('User Password Authentication failed. User: '.$user.' IP: '.$ip.' '.$pass);
            return FALSE;}

    $output=exec('$configpath/perl master_program.pl --backupID $id');  //system call
        #print "<pre>$output</pre>\n";


}
    $ip=$argv[1];
    $user=$argv[2];
    $pass=$argv[3]; 
    $configpath=$argv[4];
    $id=$argv[5];
    $stream1=create_ssh_connection($ip,$user,$pass,$configpath,$id);

?>
```

The above code will be called in a different shell script by passing the ip,password etc required.

Thank You

Comment: "can any1 confirm if this will work ?" What happened when you tested it?

Comment: I need to test it directly on the server hence need a confirmation,if the exec

Comment: so you're developing in production? Worst idea ever.

Comment: To be fair, genocide is probably the worst idea ever. Genocide, or Olive Garden.

Answer (score 0):

Based ona quick read of the [ssh2 docs at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php), you don't want to use ssh_auth_password(), that's only for authenticating users.

It appears that what you want ot do is use ssh_connect() to conenct to the remote server, followed by ssh_exec() to run your perl program.

Comment: No. You are doing it wrong. You are asking the remote server to authenticate the user, and return a yes/no answer. You are NOT asking the server to log you in - that is the ssh_connect() method as I said in my answer.